# Kubernetes secret not changing

Tags: kubernetes

So I updated a secret value but when I restart the pod it keeps the old value, I deleted the secret and created a new on and double checked the values etc and nothing seems to fix it. Something tells me that the immutable: true survives a delete secret

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  username: <super secret base64>
  password: <super secret base64>
kind: Secret
immutable: true
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: default
  labels:
    helm.toolkit.fluxcd.io/namespace: default
  name: <secretname>
  namespace: default
type: Opaque
```

Answer (score 0):

> Something tells me that the immutable: true survives a delete secret

That's right. To change immutable secret you can only re-create the secret, **follow-by** re-create the pod that depends on it.